# Store object for later use in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm working on API testing automation using Rest assured. I would like to store Response as an object after calling an API so I can validate some data using that object like, status code, body, header and all.

I tried using `System.setPropery` but it allows to store only String and if store Response as String like `System.setProperty("test", response.toString());` and try to retrieve `System.getProperty("test");` then throws the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   io.restassured.response.Response

It there a way to store an object somewhere and access it for later use?

Comment: Store the objects in a map?

Comment: Store for how long? Between runs of a program? Write it to a file or database. While the program runs? Just keep it in memory. If you mean neither, a  [mcve] would help.

Comment: store until execution going on. because value might require in other testcase until doing new request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `System.Properties` for this purpose.
Please use a simple cache store as given below.

```
public class ResponseCache {
    private static final ResponseCache myInstance = new ResponseCache();

    private final Map<String, Response> cacheStore = new HashMap<>();

    private ResponseCache() {
    }

    public static ResponseCache getInstance() {
        return myInstance;
    }

    public void addResponse(String key, Response value) {
        cacheStore.put(key, value);
    }

    public boolean exists(String key) {
        return cacheStore.containsKey(key);
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
        if (exists(key)) {
            cacheStore.remove(key);
        }
    }

    public Response get(String key) {
        return exists(key) ? cacheStore.get(key) : null;
    }

}
```

Once your execution work is completed you can remove that key.